# How can I use Perl's 'prove' with TAP producers in other languages?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, mocha.js, tap

I'm a Perl dev working with a multi-language project, including python, node.js and C. Thankfully all of these languages have TAP producer libraries. For example, I can use the `mocha` command to run Node.js scripts and get TAP output.

However, how do I integrate this with the `prove` tool? For perl, I generally put tests in `t/` and `prove -vlc t/` will run all .t files inside as perl scripts. The only thing I can think of is to `exec` a mocha command within a perl .t file.

Comment: `prove` is biased towards Perl, but fundamentally language-agnostic. The `.t` files can be any executable that outputs TAP, not necessarily a Perl script. One of my favourite techniques is writing test cases using YAML documents as .t files, then using a shebang like `#!/usr/bin/env ./run-yaml-test` to execute the test cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most direct way I can think of to use TAP as a common unit test reporting format in a multi-language project is to write a few scripts in your `t/` directory that call TAP-producing unit test drivers.

Mocha has a TAP reporting plugin called mocha-tap-reporter and invoking it from the command line is just

```
mocha --reporter mocha-tap-reporter <directory>
```

Here's an example of how might set things up in a simple project

```
.
├── node_modules
    (contents of node_modules omitted)
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── t
│   └── mocha.t
└── test
    └── multiply.js
```

In this case, `multiply.js` uses the `assert` helper and just has one test:

```
const assert = require('assert');

describe('multiply', function () {
    it('1 * 0 = 0', function () {
        assert.equal(1 * 0, 0);
    });
});
```

`mocha.t` is just a shell wrapper around `mocha --reporter mocha-tap-reporter test`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# change directory to folder containing source file
cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"
# go to project root
cd ..
# invoke mocha test runner with tap reporter
./node_modules/.bin/mocha \
    --reporter mocha-tap-reporter \
    test
```

And then if you run `prove` from the project root, you'll see this:

```
% prove
t/mocha.t .. ok
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.01 sys +  0.23 cusr  0.08 csys =  0.34 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

That being said, the `mocha-tap-reporter` plugin hasn't been updated in three years or so and looks a little unmaintained. I think that's the general situation for TAP libraries outside of the Perl community, though (having used one in an OCaml project a while back).

Comment: I don't know that a TAP formatter needs *much* maintenance, though. I may just be naive, but it's not a very complicated format / one that needs a lot of constant updating to conform to.